# What should I say when I hear the Aazan?

Tags: adhan

As the question says: What should I say when I hear the Aazan (Adhaan)?

Answer (score 9):

It is Sunnah to repeat the adhaan word by word when you hear the Mu'adhin's voice because the Prophet (peace be upon him) said:

> When you hear the Mu'adhin, **repeat what he says word for word**, then
>   invoke Allah's Blessings and Peace upon me, for whoever invokes
>   Allah's Blessings and Peace upon me (once), Allah will send His
>   Blessings and Peace tenfold upon them. Then ask Allah to grant me
>   Al-Wasilah (the most superior degree in Paradise), for it is a rank in
>   Jannah (Paradise) that is granted to only one of Allah’s Servants, and
>   I hope I will be this one. Whoever asks Allah to grant me Al-Wasilah
>   will deserve my Shafa`ah (intercession). [**[Sahih Muslim 384]**](http://sunnah.com/muslim/5/13)

**More:** [**Ruling on repeating Adhan after the Mu'adhin**](http://alifta.com/Fatawa/fatawaDetails.aspx?BookID=8&View=Page&PageNo=1&PageID=1211)

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted...!

Answer (score 1):

Adhan contains the phrases:

> حي على الصلاة
>   Come to salat
>   حي على الفلاح
>   Come to salvation

So the best reply would be accepting this invitation and joining the salat where the adhan was read in.